# How to correctly link opencl with ros?

Tags: ros-melodic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just have installed opencl in my ubuntu 18 based on [this](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/1d13c7f432ba03a8e38720c83cd973d5) tutorial.  i also find similar question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/12082/using-opencl-in-ros/) but i didn't understand it properly.  Here are the folders inside the workspace:
[image: image description]

well i tried like below, but here only opencl_headers are not creating any error.

```
 include_directories(~/intel-compute-runtime/workspace/opencl_headers/CL)
 
 target_link_libraries(~/intel-compute-runtime/workspace/build_igc/BiFModule/clang_build/install/lib)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312216/how-to-correctly-link-opencl-with-ros?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2019-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is working for me:

```
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  /usr/include/CL/
)
add_executable(save_pattern src/save_pattern.cpp)
target_link_libraries(save_pattern ${catkin_LIBRARIES} /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so)
```

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2019-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0